# Building classification tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

In the following command "Default_On_Payment" is a categorical variable,and as a result the tree should be a classification tree. But after building the tree when am doing a summarization its showing  Regression tree even though i mentioned the method as "class".

Could you kindly explain the unusual phenomenon.

```
predict_model<-tree(Default_On_Payment~Credit_History+Purposre_Credit_Taken+Property,data=tree_model,method="class")
> summary(predict_model)

Regression tree:
tree(formula = Default_On_Payment ~ Credit_History + Purposre_Credit_Taken + 
    Property, data = tree_model, method = "class")
Number of terminal nodes:  5 
Residual mean deviance:  0.1916 = 957.1 / 4995 
Distribution of residuals:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.5955 -0.3069 -0.1706  0.0000  0.4045  0.8294
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the function `tree` from the package `tree` then the parameter `method` is not for indicating which of classification and regression is to be performed but rather is to choose between `"recursive.partition"` and `"model.frame"`. See `?tree`.

You will get a classification tree if the response is a factor. Make sure that this is the case and the problem will probably be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but as explained my response variable is "Default_On_Payment" which is a categorical variable(factor)..but still after running the tree command its showing Regression tree.

Comment: If `is.factor(Default_On_Payment)` returns `TRUE` then `tree` will build a classification tree. Is it possible that even though you intend for it to be a categorical it still has a numeric type? Look at `str(Default_On_Payment)` to see.